# Trying to limit cpu usage of apache using cpulimit, but I can see it still going over my limit

Tags: php, mysql, apache, ubuntu, apache2

I'm trying to limit all pids under apache2 by using cpulimit.

I've tried specifically calling each individual pid with:

```
sudo cpulimit -p 6183 -b -l 20
```

It tells me it has detected the process, but when I used `htop` I can see the process going well over 20%.

Why is this, and is there a better way in limiting all of the apache and mysql process without targeting each pid?

Comment: And for what purpose are you doing this?

Comment: Each of these process' are maxing out my cpu while im trying to import some images from another cpu. I'm on a very limited cpu.

Comment: Why not turn off Apache?  Or get better hardware? How much time are you willing to spend on a problem you might be able to easily address with proper hardware sizing?

Comment: I need apache in this process. Well yes, getting better hardware would help, but that will be my last resort. Right now I'd like to go down this avenue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried cgroups, it allows you to control the CPU usage, amongst other things? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups. In addition you might see it go over 20% because you have a multi core system.

Comment: It's a single core cpu. I did come across cpu, so lets say my users for apache are www-data and mysql would I be able to limit the cpu usage for those users?

Comment: Have a look at this http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34334/how-to-create-a-user-with-limited-ram-usage it explains how to limit per a use RAM allocation the same can be accomplished with CPU

Comment: Okay, cgroups seem to be the way to go.